# multiple xml views with convertView android

Tags: android, listview, adapter, convertview

I am trying to write a ListView adapter that will pass a view based on one of several xml files depending on an attribute of the data that I am creating a View for.  My code works fine, except when I try to use convertView to speed up the process.  No matter how I try to use it, I either crash my program or else get strange output.  I understand *why* this would be a problem for convertView, but I strongly suspect that I can still make this work.  Can anyone advise me on how I might fix my code?
(right now I am using convertView as the name of the view that I return, even though I don't have the 'if (convertView==null)' routine working properly)

```
public class PaymentListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<Payment> mPayments;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.payment_schedule_title);
    mPayments = PaymentSchedule.get(getActivity()).getPayments();
    PaymentAdapter adapter = new PaymentAdapter(mPayments);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}


private class PaymentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Payment> {

    public PaymentAdapter(ArrayList<Payment> payments) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, payments);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Payment p = mPayments.get(position);
        //normal
        //if (convertView == null) {
        //cant work out how to use convertview conditional without screwing up project
        //it would speed it up to fix this however
        if (p.type == Payment.TYPE_START) {


            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_start, null);

            TextView remainDisplay =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remainDisplayStart);
            remainDisplay.setText(p.getRemainString());
            TextView paymentDate =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.paymentDateStart);
            paymentDate.setText(p.getDateString());
            TextView paymentDisplay =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.paymentDisplayStart);
            paymentDisplay.setText(p.getDefaultPaymentString());
            TextView aprDisplay =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.aprDisplayStart);
            aprDisplay.setText(p.getInterestRate() * 1200 + "%");
        } else {
             //if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_payment, null);
            //}
            TextView paymentDate =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.paymentDate);
            paymentDate.setText(p.getDateString());
            TextView paymentDisplay =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.paymentDisplay);
            paymentDisplay.setText(p.getPaymentString());
            TextView principalDisplay =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.principalDisplay);
            principalDisplay.setText(p.getPrincipalString());
            TextView interestDisplay =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.interestDisplay);
            interestDisplay.setText(p.getInterestString());
            TextView remainDisplay =
                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remainDisplay);
            remainDisplay.setText(p.getRemainString());
        }
        //}
        return convertView;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tryed to use `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` with `ViewHolder` instead of your code in `getView()`?

Comment: I was about to write what @anil mentioned -- you might want to check out this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Comment: It looks like that is based on position.  As I go on I want to be able to add other types based on missed payments, extra payments, penalties, etc and have them appear in the list chronologically.
I am going to try bonnyz's method of using tags.  I earlier was trying to implement if statements that referred back to the data, but could not work out how to link them to the convertView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following trick:

1. Always attach a **tag** to you `convertView` when you create it ([`setTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object))) specifying the *type* of the layout (in your case `R.layout.list_item_start` or `R.layout.list_item_payment`).
2. when you check if `convertView != null` you need also to check if the type specified by `convertView.getTag()` is the same of the layout that you are updating in order to avoid the inflate operation properly because:

   - if the **types are different** you need to overwrite `convertView` with a new inflate operation, because you need to create the proper layout type.
   - if the **types are equal** you can simply update the layout without the inflate operation

You can also improve the whole code by adopting the [ViewHolder pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!  Bonnyz's suggestion worked.  I added the following code:

```
Payment p = mPayments.get(position);

        if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() != p.type) {
            if(p.type == Payment.TYPE_START) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_start, null);
                convertView.setTag(Payment.TYPE_START);
            } else{
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_payment, null);
                convertView.setTag(Payment.TYPE_PAYMENT);
            }

        }
```

I'll be experimenting with ViewHolder also.  I just learned about that today.

Comment: It helps a lot me. Thank you @Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
String[] frName;
String[] lrName;
String[] myLocation;
Context context;
int[] imageId;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] fstName, String[] lstName, String[] location, int[] prgmImages) {
    super();
    context = mainActivity;
    frName = fstName;
    lrName = lstName;
    myLocation = location;
    imageId = prgmImages;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 12;

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView tv_frname, tv_lrname, tv_location, tv_fstname, tv_lstname;
    ImageView img;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    if (position < frName.length) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myadapterdesin, null);
        holder.tv_frname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.frname);
        holder.tv_lrname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lrname);
        holder.tv_location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.place);
        holder.tv_frname.setText(frName[position]);
        holder.tv_lrname.setText(lrName[position]);
        holder.tv_location.setText(myLocation[position]);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;

    } else if (position >= frName.length) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
        holder.tv_fstname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fstname);
        holder.tv_lstname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lstname);
        holder.tv_fstname.setText(frName[(position) - (frName.length)]);
        holder.tv_lstname.setText(lrName[(position) - (frName.length)]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[(position) - (frName.length)]);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return convertView;

}
```

}